# Why does part of my scene not appear in my final camera render but appears in all other situations?

Tags: rendering

I am new to blender and and not quite sure what info should be included here so please be patient with me.

Comment: Any information about your scene set up would be helpful. If your objects are organized into different layers, make sure all layers are selected in render layer tab, also check if the objects are visible to camera in the cycles settings in the object tab, also check if the objects are not render restricted in the outliner

Comment: In the Outliner (looks like a hierarchy), are any objects have [grayed out camera icons](http://imgur.com/a/n1wY6)? If so, they are being excluded from the render.

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspects are render layers or the render option being turned off in the outliner.
See the attached image for what I mean.
Here you can see the bottle in the 3d view but missing from the render.
Hope this helps.
[image: object missing from render]